# GeoTools WFS without DescribeFeatureType calls

Tags: java, geotools

I'm trying to access a WFS source by using the GeoTools WFS plugin as presented [here](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/wfs.html).

However, the layer I'm trying to fetch is only accessible through a proxy, and the GetCapabilities page has the plain URLs  (ie. not the proxy URLs). Thus, my requests fail as the WFS plugin attempts a DescribeFeatureType request to the wrong URL.

Is there any way to just fetch a certain GetFeature-layer, without having to query the feature schema? Could I somehow supply the schema to the plugin so no query is made?

Answer (score 0):

The [WFS-NG](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/wfs-ng.html) module is now the prefered GeoTools wfs module. However, it won't help with this issue either I'm afraid.

The best solution is to fix the server you are using (if it is a GeoServer you can [change the base URL](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#proxy-base-url)). Alternatively may be you can apply an XSLT (or regexp) to the incoming capabilities document?

Finally you can look at modifying the GeoTools code to allow the end user to supply a URL (or to guess it from the getCapababilities URL). Please read the [contribution guide lines](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/procedures/contribute.html). It would certainly do no harm to create a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOT).